# Roots to Homogeneous DE $y^{(4)}-y=0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

The homogeneous equation is $$y^{(4)}-y=0$$

The answer that was given has $e^t$, $e^{-t}$, $\sin t$, and $\cos t$ but how are the last two possible? When you solve the homogeneous equation you get $r^4=1$ so there is nothing imaginary about it right?

Comment: The roots of $r^2=1$ are $-i,i,-1,1$ so I'm not sure what you mean by "nothing imaginary about it".

Comment: I thought the roots for r^2 were only 1 and -1?

Comment: Whoops, I meant $r^4$, as you have in your question.

Answer (score 6):

$r^4-1=0\iff(r^2+1)(r^2-1)=0\iff r=1,-1,i,-i$

Thus, the general solution is $y(t)=Ae^t+Be^{-t}+Ce^{it}+De^{-it}=Ae^t+Be^{-t}+(C+D)\cos t+i(C-D)\sin t=Ae^t+Be^{-t}+P\cos t+Q\sin t$